# Tkinter Key Bind and Entry overlap

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, desktop-application, tkinter-entry

I have been working on tkinter to make an application that opens all the images inside the selected folder and shows them one by one to user. The screen has labels from a-z in form of buttons which on clicking, creates a folder and move the current image there. A Entry widget also appears under the image which has image name by default and we can rename the image from there.
[image: Please find the image of screen here]

I had to bind the keyboard buttons (a-z) with the label buttons so that when I click a button from keyboard, the images get moved to the folder. But issue comes when I try to rename the image from Entry widget. When i use buttons from a-z in the entry widget,the images get moved to the folders.
[image: entry widget]

> Code for bind:

```
root.bind("<Key>",lambda a : keyPress(a))
```

> Entry Widget:

```
image_name_input = Entry(image_frame)
image_name_input.insert(0, "Hello")
```

Comment: Binding Alt+a-z would be a quick fix

Comment: that's interesting. I'll look into this

Comment: did a hot fix by following your suggestion. Thank you!